# Second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[Is this correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lwfp.png)
Is this solution in this pic correct or not?
I want to solve this equation and that is my understanding.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial you have written is wrong. It would have been right if the equation was $y''-6y'+13y=0$ instead of $y''-6y'+13=0$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please give a title with your particular descriptions. You get help when you show your work or describe how  you went about solving it. The book is correct except for printer's typo given by Aniket.

Comment: Obviously, there is a typo in the picture ! One more !!

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment, if there is no typo and the equation is really as you have written it, then the right approach would be to assume $z=y'$.Then we can write $y''-6y'+13=0$ as $z'-6z+13=0$.

Therefore, we solve the above equation as follows:
$$z'= 6z-13$$
$$6z'= 6(6z-13)$$
$$\frac{d(6z-13)}{(6z-13)}=6 \,\ dt$$
$$\int \frac{d(6z-13)}{(6z-13)}=6 \int dt$$
$$\ln |6z-13| =6t+k$$
$$6z-13=e^{6t+k}=c_1e^{6t}$$
$$6\frac{dy}{dt}=c_1e^{6t}+13$$
$$6 \int dy=c_1e^{6t} \int dt+13 \int dt$$
$$y(t)=\frac{c_1e^{6t}}{36}+\frac{13t}{6}+c_2$$
This is the required solution.

And if the equation you have written has some typo error i.e. there is a term of $y$ with coefficient $13$ and no constant term, then your solution is right.